# Show this set is compact set.(Topology)

Tags: general-topology

Let continuous function, $f$

$f$ is defined by $f : (\mathbb{R^2}, U) \to (Y, T_{Y}) $ $by $ $f(p) = p$ for $p \in Y$ and $f(p)  = \phi$ for $p \notin Y$

(Here the $U$ is the usual topology, $Y$ is bounded set on $\mathbb{R}$ , $T_Y$ is a  subspace topology on $(\mathbb{R^2},U)$.)

Show $T_Y$ is a compact or not

---

There is someone who suggest the above question said $(Y,T_Y)$ is a compact.

Here is the his grounds.

$\exists K = [a,b] \times [c,d] s.t. Y \subset K$

Surely $K$ is a compact in $U$, Hence by continuity $f(K)$ is a compact.

Hence, $f(K) = Y$ is a compact

But my thought **$T_Y$ is not compact set, generally.**

Take a $Y=\{(x,y) \vert x^2 + y^2 <1 \}$ (Surely it is bounded But not compact in $U$)

Hence taking the open set, $G_n = \{ (x,y)\vert x^2 + y^2 < 1 - {1 \over n} \}$ 
in $(Y,T_Y)$

Then, $Y$ Can't be covered  by finite number of the $G_n$.

**So here is the question.**

Which one is correct? I'm not sure my thought is right or not  because I couldn't find his mistakes. If my thought is incorrect, What the point do I have a mistake?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that $f$ is well-defined ?

Comment: No I haven't  check that. Only I have done just solved the question he suggested.

Comment: Why "hence $f(K) = Y$"?

Comment: @xbh, I edited the function, $f$.

Comment: Why $\varnothing $ should be a member of $Y$? It is the "empty set", it is a **subset** of every set, but generally not an element…

Comment: I voted to close your question because it is unclear what you are asking. 1. What is $f(p)$ for $p \notin Y$? 2. You define $f$, but what is the connection with $T_Y$? Do you perhaps assume that $f$ is continuous? 3. I **guess** you mean that $Y$ is a retract of $\mathbb R^2$. If so, please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining f(p) = p for p in R$^2$ most likely means, after
clarifying what was intended by sloppy use of quantifiers,
for all p in R$^2$, f(p) = p.
Thus f is the identity function and consequently
Y = R$^2$ with the usual topology.
Thus Y is not compact.

After your edit there is the unexplained term "o.w."
Defining f as the identity function over Y and as the empty set for points not in Y results in the codomain of f being outside of Y, an inconsistency.

Comment: I edited the function f(p) =p for p in Y. Sorry for late editing the post. So your function should be f(p)=p for p in Y. So it is not identity.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang.  See my edit of my answer.

Comment: why does the codomain outside of the Y? By definition of the topology, Does $\phi \in (Y, T_Y)$? Hence could we say codomain is Y? I can't figure out the inconsistency you've meant.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang.   No, the empty set is not in Y.  f is from R$^2$ into Y;  empty set in (Y,T$_Y$) is nonsense.